# Upstart: report (email, log) on respawn and failure

Tags: 12.04, upstart

I would like to get an email when an upstart job fails and respawns, and when all respawns are depleted, and the job fails.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Upstart automatically logs when jobs are respawning and when it gives up on them.

```
[266017.061509] init: foo main process (11582) terminated with status 1
[266017.061684] init: foo respawning too fast, stopped
```

So just watch the logs for these messages and send an email alert when they are seen.

Comment: Ok, so how does one go about setting up a "watch" to send an email alert?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`pre-start`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#pre-start) stanza to send email but I think it's better to use [`post-stop`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#post-stop) which has the needed variables from last run.

> If  the  job was stopped normally, the **RESULT** environment variable
>   will
>          be ok, otherwise if the job was stopped because it has failed  it  will
>          be failed.
>
> When  the  job has failed, the process that failed will be given in the
>          **PROCESS** environment variable.  This may be pre-start, post-start, main,
>          pre-stop  or  post-stop;  it  may  also be the special value respawn to
>          indicate that the job was stopped because it hit the respawn limit.

**Source:** `man stopped`

**References:**

- [Upstart Intro, Cookbook and Best Practises: respawn](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn)